# How to write the following Queries in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My tables:
Musician (id, mname, aname, percentage(**fee for the agemt**))
Singer (id, gender)
Instrumentalist (id, instrument)
Agent (aname, street, city, zip)
Festival (title, place, sdate, edate)
Event (title, edate, etime)
Booked (id, title **(Event.title)**, edate, etime, salary)

1. for each festival, find the agent , its overall profit this festival is the highest. Presented the festival's name, agent's name, and its overall profit.
2. Festival.title="Autumn Festival" and salary<8000,
   find the date and time of the event, that taking part in only
   instrumentalists, and the number of instrumentalists at this event is the lowest.

**1:**

```
select f1.title , aname , sum (salary*percentage/100) as feeAgent 
from festival as f1 , booked , musician 
where booked.id=musician.id and booked.edate between f1.sdate and f1.edate
group by  f1.title , aname
having sum (salary*percentage/100)>any(select sum (salary*percentage/100)
                                       from festival as f1 , booked , musician 
                                       where booked.id=musician.id and     booked.edate between f1.sdate and f1.edate
                                       group by musician.aname)
```

**2:**

```
select event.edate, event.etime
from event, festival as f1, booked natural join musician natural join instrumentalist 
where event.title=f1.title and f1.title Like 'spring%' and booked.salary<8000 and booked.edate between f1.sdate and f1.edate
group by event.edate, event.etime
having count(booked.title)<all(select count(*)
           from event,festival as f1,booked natural join musician natural join instrumentalist
           where event.title=f1.title and f1.title Like 'spring%' and booked.salary<8000 and booked.edate between f1.sdate and f1.edate
           group by booked.title)
```

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: MYSQL or SQLServer? They are not the same!

Comment: Can you try to rewrite question no.2? It is unclear to me what you mean.

Comment: @Bernd Buffen - I did

Comment: @RiggsFolly- I work with - postgresql.

Comment: @friedemann_bach 
2. Find Autumn Festival events where instrumentalists are getting less 
salary than 8000,
but the number of instrumentalists in this event is the lowest.
show the date and time of this event.

Comment: Please provide some example data e.g. on http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @friedemann_bach http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/35773/4263

Comment: The provided data is not working, please check again (dates should be given in "YYYY-MM-DD"). Show us what you tried so far and give us the expected output.